# Output Power Shell Results

Tags: powershell, file, text, output

the title says it all. I have a working PS Code and would like the results to be output to a text or excel file.

```
$computers = get-content 
"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\David\FINAL\RamCheck\input.txt"

Perform an operation for each row in the file
foreach ($strComputer in $computers) {
$colSlots = Get-WmiObject -Class "win32_PhysicalMemoryArray" -namespace 
"root\CIMV2" -computerName $strComputer
write-host ""
$colSlots = Get-WmiObject -Class "win32_PhysicalMemoryArray" -namespace 
"root\CIMV2" -computerName $strComputer
$colRAM = Get-WmiObject -Class "win32_PhysicalMemory" -namespace 
"root\CIMV2" - 
computerName $strComputer
$NumSlots = 0


$SlotsFilled = 0
$TotMemPopulated = 0

$colRAM | ForEach {
“Memory Installed: ” + $_.DeviceLocator
“Memory Size: ” + ($_.Capacity / 1GB) + ” GB”       
$TotMemPopulated = $TotMemPopulated + ($_.Capacity / 1GB)
if ($_.Capacity = 0)
{write-host "found free slot"}



write-host ""
write-host "=== Summary Memory Slot Info for computer:" $strComputer "==="
write-host "Total Memory Populated = " $TotMemPopulated "GB"
```

i have tried to use

```
export-csv -append $fileOutput -Encoding utf8
```

[Attached is a picture of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5seK.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each PC you are checking you can construct an object and add that object to an array, then export that array to a CSV.There are older examples but this uses the newer PSCustomObject which is nice to learn how to use.

```
#Create an array
$Array = @()

#Loop through all your computers again (or add to an existing loop)
foreach ($strComputer in $computers)
{
    $compresults = New-Object -TypeName [PSCustomObject]@{

        Computer = $strComputer
        Memory = $TotMemPopulated
        SlotsFilled = $SlotsFilled
    }

    $array += $compresults
}

#Export the array to CSV
$Array | export-csv $fileOutput -Encoding UTF8
```

Answer (score 1):

`Export-Csv` isn't going to work in a good fashion because your input isn't meant to be represented in table. You generate a text string that has formatting that's only going to be understandable for humans.

If you wanted to make it exportable as a CSV you'd have to change your output in a way that makes it possible to do so. For instance you could output arrays with the values and skip the text.

To just output text you'd use something like [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-6).

```
Out-File -Encoding utf8 -InputObject $fileOutput
```

Your scrip overall is a mess, using the wrong type of quotes, missing closing brackets and so on. As it is right now it shouldn't be working at all.